# Redirect search.php to 404.php

Tags: 404-error, themes

anyone knows how to redirect search.php to 404.php when no search results found?

I've got more than 1000s of soft 404 errors due to this search feature. I just want to redirect nothing found results to 404.php. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the wp_query->set_404 and status_header in a condition if no results found.

```
  global $wp_query;
  $wp_query->set_404();
  status_header(404);
```